# Django ckeditor codesnippet plugin shows codes without color

Tags: django, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my django project, everything is working fine, but when add code snippet there is only simple text code without colors but in my admin panel it is normal.

[image: Admin panel]

[image: Template]

Answer (score 1):

add it in html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/styles/default.min.css">　
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/styles/monokai.min.css">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).